# How to best sort an array of strings with comma delimited numbers _and_ symbols in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

What's the best approach to sort() an array of strings containing comma delimited numbers *and* symbols in JavaScript?

My array looks like this:

```
var uniqueValues = ["<100,000", ">100,000", ">250,000", ">500,000", ">1,000,000", ">750,000"]
```

and I need it to look like this:

```
[">1,000,000", ">750,000", ">500,000", ">250,000", ">100,000", "<100,000"]
```

Below you can see what I've tried thus far.  #1 to get around the alphanumeric issue (using a combo of sort & localeCompare) and #2 to attempt to weigh ">" higher than "<" for example (thanks to this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31939834/how-to-sort-a-list-with-symbols-in-js), but I can't figure out how to both weigh the symbol, as well as correctly sort the comma-delimited numbers.  Here are the approaches I've tried without success:

```
1.   uniqueValues.sort((a,b) => a.localeCompare(b));

2.   var sortOrder = {
        '>': 1,
        '<': 2
     }

     uniqueValues.sort(function (a, b) {
        var oa = sortOrder[a[0]] || 2;
        var ob = sortOrder[b[0]] || 2;
        if (oa > ob)
          return 1;
        else if (oa < ob)
          return -1;
        else
          return 0;
      });
```

Comment: not the best solution.. but you could replace '<' with '-' and '>' with '+'. then just sort and replace back.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A slightly different approach is to use a parse method since you don't exactly want to sort according to string values. You rather want to sort according to the order of magnitude they represent.

Let assume that each expression should be interpreted as a bigger number ('>') or smaller number ('<'). That can be translated to +1 / -1. Then, replace all dots and commas in the remaining part for it to be an integer and sum both parts.

The solution can be as simple as a sort according to that parse method.

```js
var uniqueValues = ["<100,000", ">100,000", ">250,000", ">500,000", ">1,000,000", ">750,000"];

function parseExpr(exp) {
   return (exp[0] == '<' ? -1 : 1) + parseInt(exp.replace(/[,.]/g, '').substr(1));
}

uniqueValues.sort((a,b) => parseExpr(b) - parseExpr(a));

console.log(uniqueValues);
```

Comment: Beautifully elegant, and very well explained.  Thank you @Frederik.L  I greatly appreciate it.

Comment: You probably want `-` in the sort func instead of `<`.

Comment: @codelinquint don't forget to tag the correct answer (well in this case the one you like the most, since most are correct).

Comment: @georg Updated. Thank you!

Comment: Also, this doesn't seem to returns correct results for e.g. `["<1", "<3", ">1"]` (unless I'm misunderstanding the question).

Comment: @georg I am getting these results on my end: ["<3", ">1", "<1"], which is [2, 2, 0] on a comparison level. I think <3 can be equivalent to >1, beside <3 being cuter sometimes. Can the OP confirm that it's wanted behavior here?

Answer (score 1):

Add 1 to the number if it includes `>`, then sort:

```js
var uniqueValues = ["<100,000", ">100,000", ">250,000", ">500,000", ">1,000,000", ">750,000"]
var s2i = (s) => {
  let n = parseInt(s.replace(/[^\d]/g, ''))
  return n + (s.includes('>') ? 1 : 0)
};
uniqueValues.sort((a,b) => Math.sign(s2i(a) - s2i(b)));
console.log(uniqueValues)
```

Comment: This is also a very elegant solution. This solution has taught me about `Math.sign` and `includes`.  Thank you!  (I'm really struggling with who to credit with the 'best' answer)...

Answer (score 1):

Not the most elegant or robust solution, but very simple:

```
uniqueValues.sort((a, b) => {
  const aStr = a.substring(1)
  const bStr = b.substring(1)
  if (aStr == bStr) {
    return a < b ? 1 : -1
  }
  const aInt = parseInt(bStr.split(',').join(''))
  const bInt = parseInt(aStr.split(',').join(''))
  return aInt - bInt
})
```

Comment: Thank you @dzuremar, I appreciate your time, and the very simple construction of an answer is easy for me to read and understand.

Answer (score 0):

Create a map of strings to numeric values using [Array#reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) then sort using the numeric values from the map:

```js
var uniqueValues = ["<100,000", ">100,000", ">250,000", ">500,000", ">1,000,000", ">750,000"];

var valuesMap = uniqueValues.reduce(function(map, v) {
  // convert to number by removing all non numeric characters, parsing, and convert the sign to a number
  map[v] = { 
    value: +v.replace(/[^\d]/g, ''), 
    sign: v[0] === '>' ? 1 : -1
  };

  return map;
}, Object.create(null));

// sort using the corresponding values from the map - if the values are equal compare the signs
uniqueValues.sort(function(a, b) { 
  var am = valuesMap[a];
  var bm = valuesMap[b];

  return bm.value - am.value || bm.sign - am.sign;
});


console.log(uniqueValues);
```

And the ES6 version using a [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) instead of a plain object:

```js
var uniqueValues = ["<100,000", ">100,000", ">250,000", ">500,000", ">1,000,000", ">750,000"];

// convert to number by removing all non numeric characters, parsing, and convert the sign to a number
const valuesMap = uniqueValues.reduce((map, v) =>
  map.set(v, {
    value: +v.replace(/[^\d]/g, ''),
    sign: v[0] === '>' ? 1 : -1
  }), new Map());

// sort using the corresponding values from the map - if the values are equal compare the signs
uniqueValues.sort((a, b) => {
  const am = valuesMap.get(a);
  const bm = valuesMap.get(b);

  return bm.value - am.value || bm.sign - am.sign
})

console.log(uniqueValues);
```

Comment: You probably want `*` for the sign, rather than `+`.

Comment: Thank you @Ori Drori, I appreciate you taking the time to solve this.  I especially appreciate you writing it in both ES5 and ES6.  However beautiful the answer may be, it's a bit difficult to digest so I am not selecting it as the answer.

Comment: @codelinquint - totally understandable. It was an enjoyable question nonetheless.

Answer (score 0):

Convert your Strings into Numbers, and use an *epsilon* estimation instead of `<` and `>` for comparing.

Here's the code:

```
var a = ["<100,000", ">100,000", ">250,000", ">500,000", ">1,000,000", ">750,000"];
var epsilon = 0.000001; // Choose whatever precision you require.

function toNumber(x) {
  var signedEpsilon = (x[0] === "<" ? -epsilon : epsilon); // signed epsilon.
  return parseFloat(x.slice(1).replace(/,/g, "")) + signedEpsilon;
}

a.sort((x, y) => toNumber(x) < toNumber(y));
```